# Rotate ticks labels of artist_axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to rotate yticks labels from plot from [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axisartist/demo_axisline_style.html)

[image]

In matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/axis_artist_api.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axis_artist.Ticks) I found:

> set_tick_out(b) set True if tick need to be rotated by 180 degree.

I tried:

```
ax.axis['yzero'].major_ticks.set_tick_out(True)
```

and

```
ax.axis['yzero'].minor_ticks.set_tick_out(True)
```

But it doesn't help me. How can I achieve that result?

Comment: When I run this with [`ax.axis['yzero'].major_ticks.set_tick_out(False)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7CfS.png) and with [`ax.axis['yzero'].major_ticks.set_tick_out(True)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVWgI.png) I see a clear difference.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Do you see the rotation of yticks? Because I see no difference.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich do you want to rotate the tick *labels* instead?

Comment: Yes, with `False` they point to the left, with `True` they point to the right.

Comment: @gmds Yes, I was mistaken. I want to rotate labels.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich see my answer

Comment: Before asking the next question, check ["Parts of a figure"](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will remember it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.axis['yzero'].major_ticks.set_tick_out(True)` changes the direction of the *ticks*.

`ax.axis['yzero'].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction('right')` changes the direction of the tick *labels*.